# Spying in Blue prism

Tags: automation, sap-gui, blueprism, spying

I am using SAP mode for spying the elements in SAP GUI.

I want to click on a label in which label will be the input parameter.

For instance, if I pass "Customer", then Customer label should be clicked.

But label text field comes under Informational note.

[image: Captured by Application navigator - Informational Note is disabled]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The BluePrism SAP Mode is connecting with SAP using SAP Scripting language. The standard queries in SAP look like that:

```
session.findbyid("ID").Activate
```

The BluePrism implementation is the simplest one possible - they are using only the standard queries. BluePrism always finds the items in SAP using exact ID. Because of that, using standard BluePrism spying tool, it is impossible to search for items using different kind of parameters (e.g. label, position etc. etc).

If you'd like to implement something like that, then you'll need to:

1. Create a new object (we call it SAP - Utility)
2. Connect to SAP using SAP API
3. Use applicable SAP scripting method. session.FindByName() or session.FindByLabel()

That's no easy task!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will try using SAP API to achieve the task and will get back to you.